# Omit Parent class attributes in java

Tags: java, oop

I have two java class:

```
class Employee{
  private name;
  private annualSalary;

 public Employee(String name, double annualSalary){

}
}
```

and

```
class HourlyEmployee extends Employee{

 public HourlyEmployee(String name, double annualSalary, double hourlySalary){
 super(salary, annualSalary);
this.hourly = hourlySalary;
}
}
```

Is there a way I can get rid of the `annualSalary` from the inherited class understanding that the annualSalary = hourlySalary * 200? by default when the HourlyEmployee class is created. The value for annualSalary will be empty or set to hourlySalary * 200.

Comment: This is a pretty trivial thing bro...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `annualSalary` and pass `hourlySalary * 200` to super-class constructor.

```
public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee {

    private double hourlySalary;

    public HourlyEmployee(String name, double hourlySalary) {
        super(name, hourlySalary * 200);
        this.hourlySalary = hourlySalary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a good solution. If the hourly employee's hourly salary changes, the annual salary will become inconsistent.

Comment: @TedHopp Agreed. Didn't try to think of the best solution, just answered OP's problem of "*set* to hourlySalary * 200"

Answer (score 2):

Your class structure is wrong because not all employees get an annual salary. Get rid of `annualSalary` from `Employee` and create two subclasses: `HourlyEmployee` that has an hourly salary and a `SalariedEmployee` that has an annual salary. If needed, introduce an abstract method `getAnnualSalary` in `Employee` (and make `Employee` abstract) and implement it differently in the two subclasses.

```
abstract class Employee {
    private String name;

    public Employee(String name) { ... }
    public abstract double getAnnualSalary();
}

class SalariedEmployee extends Employee {
    private double annualSalary;

    public SalariedEmployee(String name, double annualSalary) {
        super(name);
        this.annualSalary = annualSalary;
    }

    @Override
    public double getAnnualSalary() { return annualSalary; }
}

class HourlyEmployee extends Employee {
    private double hourlySalary;

    public HourlyEmployee(String name, double hourlySalary) {
        super(name);
        this.hourlySalary = hourlySalary;
    }

    @Override
    public double getAnnualSalary() { return 200 * hourlySalary; }
}
```

You might also want to explore using interfaces to define employee behavior, rather than using a base class.

Answer (score 1):

Needing to omit parent class attributes is a code smell called [refused bequest](https://refactoring.guru/smells/refused-bequest). If an hourly employee does not have a yearly salary, the class that represents an hourly employee should not inherit from the class that represents a salaried employee.

The solution is extracting the parts they have in common to a separate class, or several different classes, depending on the case. In your current contrived example there's nothing the two classes have in common, and I see no point in using inheritance to begin with.